# Use External standalone-full.xml by the RHPAM kie pod in Openshift

Tags: openshift, jbpm, openshift-enterprise

I just want to use customized standalone-full.xml in the RHPAM kie server pod which is running in Openshift. I have created the configmap from file and not sure how to set it.

I created the configmap like this

```
oc create configmap my-config --from-file=standalone-full.xml.
```

And edited the deploymentconfig of rhpam kie server,

```
   volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /opt/eap/standalone/configuration
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: my-config
```

It starts a new container,with sttaus container creating and fails with error(sclaing down 1 to 0)

Am i setting the configmap correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the configmap in a pod as a volume. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume)'s a good example: just add '*volumes*' (to specify configmap as a volume) and '*volumeMounts*' (to specify mount point) blocks in the pod's spec:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "ls /etc/config/" ]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        # Provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want
        # to add to the container
        name: special-config
  restartPolicy: Never
```